# dp:url-open's timeout value is getting ignored in datapower

Tags: ibm-datapower

I am providing a timeout of one second , however when the URL is down it is taking 120+ seconds for the response to come. Is there some variable or something that overrides the timeout in do:url-open ?

**Update:** I was calling the dp:url-open on request-transformation as well as on response-transformation. So the overriden timeout is 60 sec, adding both side it was becoming 120 sec.

Here's how I am calling this (I am storing the time before and after dp:url-open calls, and then returning them in the response):
[image]

**Case 1:** When the url is reachable I am getting a result like:
[image]

**Case 2:** When url is not reachable:
[image]

**Update: FIXED:** It seems the port that I was using was getting timed-out in the firewall first there it used to spend 1 minute. I was earlier trying to hit an application running on port 8077, later I changed that to 8088, And I started seeing the same timeout that I was passing.

Answer (score 0):

The `do:url-open()` timeout only affects the operation done in the script but not the service itself. It depends on how you have built the solution but the time-out from the `do:url-open()` should be honored.
You can check this by setting logs to `debug` and adding a `<xsl:message>Before url-open</xsl:message>` and one `after` to see in the log if it is your url-open call or teh service that waits 120+ sec.

If it is the url-open you have most likely some error in the script and if it is the service that halts the response you need to return from the script (or throw an error depending on your needs) to halt the service.

You can set the time-out for the service itself or set a time-out in the User Agent for the specific URL you are calling as well.
Please note that the time-out will terminate the service after that time if you set it on service level so 1 sec. would not be recommended!

Comment: Hi Anders, I am storing the date and time in two variables before and after url open and returning those in the response. I have updated the original questions with relevant screenshots. I am getting no time-difference when the url is reachable and a delay of 1min+ when the url is down.

Comment: I did some more analysis and found that my timeout value is not actually getting ignored but 60 sec is getting added to my timeout. For example when I kept the time out value 7 sec, actual timeout was 1 min 10 sec, when my timeout was 37 sec actual timeout was 1 min 40 sec, similarly 1 min 50 sec for my timeout value of 47 sec.

Comment: And what happens if you change the Service time-out?

Comment: The service that I am calling using dp URL open is not running when I am seeing this timeout value to be be more than what I am configuring.Besides I have another java application that gets the content of same URL and that is timing out in exactly same amount of time that I am configuring in code in milliseconds. Regarding my mpgw timeouts, my "back side timeout" and "front side timeout" both are 10 sec.

Comment: It seems the port that I was using was getting timedout in the firewall first there it used to spend 1 minute. I was earlier trying to hit an application running on port 8077, later I changed that to 8088, And I started seeing the same timeout that I was passing.